# Sun Grid Engine - print task I am on in my array job

Tags: sungridengine

I've been using http://wiki.gridengine.info/wiki/index.php/Simple-Job-Array-Howto as my reference.

How do I print the number of the task I am currently on? So far I have this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Grid Engine options (lines prefixed with #$)
#$ -t 1-2
#$ -N test$SGE_TASK_ID.txt
#$ -cwd                  
#$ -l h_rt=24:00:00 
#$ -l h_vmem=10G


# Initialise the environment modules
. /etc/profile.d/modules.sh

echo $SGE_TASK_ID
```

This gives me nothing.

Comment: `/bin/sh` doesn't support arrays at all (they're originally a ksh extension also supported by bash, zsh and others), and your "reference" is calling `/bin/sh` "bash", which it isn't. Which is to say -- these folks are experts about Sun Grid Engine, not about shell programming, and they're *definitely* not talking about shell arrays, since the shell they're using doesn't support 'em. As such, the "shell" tag is quite off-topic here: Just being a shell expert doesn't make one able to answer your question, which is specifically about the Sun Grid Engine.

Comment: (`/bin/sh` is guaranteed to be a shell implementing POSIX sh [an early-90s standard] on modern systems, though on sufficiently ancient operating systems it can also be Bourne [which dates back to the 70s]. Even if it's implemented by a modern shell such as bash or ksh, there's no guarantee of extensions -- such as arrays -- being available when invoked in this mode; if one wants extensions to be reliably available, one is obliged to use a shebang pointing to a shell implementing them).